# Qt Creatorにおける雛形の作成

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Qt creatorを用いて開発をしている者です.非Qtのc++アプリケーションを作成すると,Hello worldと出力されるプログラムの雛形が作成されます。この初期状態を任意に変更することは可能ですか?具体的にはマクロをファイル作成時に記載したり,boostのライブラリをincludeしておきたいと考えているのですが.
可能ならその方法も教えていただけると助かります.
qtcreator-4.5.0-2です.

Answer (score 0):

私はやった経験はないのですが、方法はあるようです。下記記事を参考にしてみてください。

[Qt Creator のスニペット機能とウィザード機能 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/task_jp/items/f3703b94646cd5ee2cd6#%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD)

Comment: ありがとうございます。Qtcreator使いやすいのですが日本語のリファレンスが少ないのは難点ですね><とりあえずやってみます。